# How to switch out a backtrack distro? (Multiple Ideas)

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, windows, gparted

Got myself in a little over my head in partitions. Currently I have an ubuntu 11.10 distro and a backtrack distro on my hard drive. I can't run Diablo 3 on a virtual box successfully, so I made a backtrack virtualbox. I've still got the windows installation CD's that came with the computer, so my question is how should I go around switching my partition from backtrack/ubuntu to windows/ubuntu?

Heres what my gparted window looks like:
/dev/sda1 is file system ext4 and is my ubuntu partition
/dev/sda2 is file system extended and is my backtrack partition,
it has alot of partitions under it...
sdas 5 6 and 7, where 5 and 7 are linux-swap, 6 is ext4

Im worried that If I try and delete my backtrack partition I'm going to run into problems booting my drive. Am I right in this fear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal solution: Burn a GParted live usb, delete your backtrack partition, and hope for the best. In theory, as long as Ubuntu is installed to sda1, the system will still work. But be sure to backup your data first. ALSO: A word of warning, windows installs completed after installing Ubuntu sometimes overwrite GRUB, manual intervention may required, but nothing too hard.